# HTML text is overlapping other text

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/other/fav.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/other/style.css">
</head>
<body class="body">
<font size="6"><div align="center">Come back later.</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have this CSS in `style.css`:

```
.footer { 
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed; 
  bottom: 5px; 
  font-family:verdana;
  padding: 0px;
} 

.body {
  background-color:F2F2F2;
  font-family:verdana;
}
```

Finally, the contents of the `/var/www/other/foot.txt` file is:

```
<div class="footer">
<font size="2">Contact:
<a href="skype:myskype">Skype</a> | <a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">Email</a></font>
</div>
```

**The problem** is that any text with the `<div class="footer">` overwrites anything in the `<body>`.

Here's an example:

[image]

The `Contact: Skype | Email` is has the `<div class="footer">` attribute while `Skype Account` is just in the HTML.

Comment: One issue is that you have invalid nesting: `<font size="6"><div align="center">Come back later.</font>`. Don't use the `font` tag, it's seriously outdated. Second, there's no closing `div` tag

Comment: Since this is a client-side problem, PHP has little to do with – apart from maybe the fact that it does not generate the HTML code you want, or that code is invalid. So go validate your HTML output first.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the footer in `<pre>` tags?  I would assume that messes with CSS hard..

Comment: @SamSullivan To make it use any HTML in the text file

Comment: Second, you're using `position:fixed; ` for the footer. I can't see your page but that will take it out of the render context and it could easily overlap anything else at the bottom of your page

Comment: I would replace your PHP `file_get_contents()` with `<?php include('/var/www/other/foot.txt'); ?>`.  Any HTML will be printed to the screen normally.

Comment: Following on from @SamSullivan... are you including your footer **after** you close your HTML tag? First step for you is to use a valid HTML structure... try the W3C validator purely to get it right to start with

Comment: This is wrong is two spots `<font size="6"><div align="center">`. Don't use the font tag (use CSS) and the align attrribute was deprecated a long time ago. Use `text-align:center`

Answer (score 0):

Change position to absolute.

```
    .footer { 
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute; 
  bottom: 5px; 
  font-family:verdana;
  padding: 0px;
} 

.body {
  background-color:F2F2F2;
  font-family:verdana;
}
```

Comment: It still does it, the only difference is that it doesn't move if I scroll up/down.

Comment: try using position:absolute for both texts so that they go in different places.